# Manipulate external DOM (prevent text selection) while avoiding DOM access from directive controller

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

**Scenario...**

I'm building a date picker directive and untill now I managed to keep strict separation between template/controller concerns. The controller builds a month array full of day objects. The template uses `ng-repeat="day in days"` to render  current month dates.

Currently I am building an interval selection method which is invoked by: `ng-mousedown="startSelection(date.dayId);"`. While the click is pressed a range of dates is defined in the model as the selected dates, and highlighted in the template via a css class. On mouse button release the range is defined one last time in order to obtain the final date selection.

This works fine, however there is a small issue that needs to be tackled. While the mouse is pressed and `startSelection` does it's job also the browser highlights the text in the specific blue shade. I want to prevent this behavior by attaching a `no-select` css class to the body element while the mouse is pressed, and then removing it when selection sequence has ended.

(*I choose the body element because if the cursor slides of the directive into the app body, text will be selected from everywhere in the page.*)

```
.no-select { 
    -webkit-touch-callout:none; 
    -webkit-user-select:none; 
    -khtml-user-select:none; 
    -moz-user-select:none; 
    -ms-user-select:none; 
    user-select:none;
}
```

**... and Question**

And here's what troubles me: Since we are not supposed to manipulate DOM from the controller (especially external elements) in order to facilitate unit testing, what is the recommended way to do this operation? Are there any guidelines/best practices for fringe cases like this one? Is it overkill to create a service dedicated for text selection prevention? I guess that would best fit as a method into an utils service.

**Directive controller:**

```
app.directive("caDatePicker", function () {
    return {
        ...
        controller: function ($scope) {
            ...
            $scope.startSelection = function (dayId) {
                angular.element(document.querySelector('body')).addClass('no-select');
                ...
            };
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Slightly different scenario:**
What if I add a class on the directive element `<ca-date-picker></ca-date-picker>` like in the following code sample. Is this ok practice? Does this infringe the controller-template separation of concerns guideline?

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.addClass("no-select");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you use a `$rootScope.isSelecting` (inject $rootScope in your directive as well) variable, and then add `ng-class="{ 'no-select': isSelecting }"` on your body element?

Comment: It seems that this approach prevents my directive from touching the dom while at the same time it inhibits text selection. Also it is usable from anywhere else in the app. Do you think that this should be packaged as a service in the app?

Comment: One more issue that concerns me: how strictly these situations should be enforced? Is it harmful to have even a few of these situations occuring, or it is best not do to any DOM manipulation from controller at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a boolean in the controller and then in your directive you could watch a change on this model attribute and do your dom manipulation in the directive :

```
controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.dayId = "";
    $scope.selectionStarted = false;
    $scope.startSelection = function (dayId) {
       $scope.dayId = dayId;
       $scope.selectionStarted = true;

    };
    ...
}
```

then in your directive :

```
$scope.$watch('selectionStarted', function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if(newValue) {
            angular.element(document.querySelector('body')).addClass('no-select');
          }
        });
```

Basically take this as a rule of thumb. **Never** ever manipulate your dom in your controllers **ever**.
Your controller is the glue that controls the behaviour of your view and the directive is what depending on the status of your controller $scope variables is what manipulates the dom.

if your element that you want to manipulate is outside of your direcitve scope or controller scope. but an attribute of that controller is responsible for if or not the dom manipulation should be applied. You can do this :

in your template :

```
ng-class="noSelectBoolean ? 'no-select-css-class' : 'select-css-class'"
```

in your controller that is in scope of your template :

```
.controller(function($scope) {
     $scope.noSelectBoolean = false;
     $scope.$on('applyNoSelect', function(event, value) {
     $scope.noSelectBoolean = value;
     }
}
```

and lastly in your controller that decides if it should be applied or not :

```
.controller(function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.noSelect  = function(value){
     $rootScope.$broadcast('applyNoSelect', value);
   }
}
```

for more a more indepth explaination check out a previous answer I submitted :

[Event broadcasting in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744713/access-ng-model-data-outside-of-the-controller/31744969#31744969)

Comment: Well, this is a slightlly different approach than the one I was following. Indeed it does the thing I want: preventing text selection, but it still doesn't really help me understand if it is ok to manipulate dom elements straight from the parent controller or directive controller, especially dom elements that are outside of the directive.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa hi adrian I updated my answer. basically take this as a golden rule. never manipulate your dom in a controller. keep your controllers as mean and lean as you can.

Comment: for dom elements outside of your directive you can use your template do manipulate your dom depending on a scope variable. I will add this to my answer as an example

Comment: Well, that makes it clear, no DOM manipulation at all. Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianMoisa I updated my answer for your specific use case when you are out of your deciding controller scope